# matlab struct modify array elements

Tags: matlab, struct

I have a struct array field seg.startscan.
I want to erase some of its elements.

For example the elements corresponding to the indices stored contained in an array INDS.

The followings are ny try and the relative errors:

1)

> > seg.startscan(INDS) = [ ];

??? Scalar structure required for this assignment.

2)

> > seg(INDS).startscan = [ ];

??? Insufficient outputs from right hand side to satisfy comma
separated
list expansion on left hand side.  Missing [] are the most likely
cause.

3)

> > startscans = seg.startscan;
> >         startscans(INDS) = [ ];
> >         fldnm = 'startscan';
> >         seg.(fldnm) = startscans;

??? Insufficient outputs from right hand side to satisfy comma
separated
list expansion on left hand side.  Missing [] are the most likely
cause.

4)

> > startscans = seg.startscan;
> >         startscans(INDS) = [ ];
> >         fldnm = 'startscan';
> >         [seg.(fldnm)] = startscans;

??? Too many output arguments.

5)
as suggested here: [1](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/):

```
>>startscans = seg.startscan;
startscans(INDS) = [ ];
fldnm = 'startscan';
[seg.(fldnm)] = startscans;
```

??? Too many output arguments.

Do you have any ideas?
Probably I do not grasp the idea behind the struct arrays..

Let's say that my input is:

```
>>seg.startscan
ans=
1
ans=
2
ans=
3
ans=
4
>>INDS = [1 3];
```

then my expected output is:

```
>>seg.startscan 

ans=
2
ans=
4
```

This gave a quite similar solution, but it not vectorized and not completely right

```
 >>for i = 1:numel(INDS)
    seg(IND(i)).startscan=[];
 end
 >>seg.startscan 

ans=
[]
ans=
2
ans=
[]
ans=
4
```

Help please!

Thank you!

Comment: You can't erase a field for some of the indices. You can erase the whole records indicated by `INDS`, with all their fields. Does the struct array have more fields other than `startscan`?

Comment: Yes. It also has a seg.stopscan

Comment: You can't have for example `seg(1)` with only field `startscan` _and_ `seg(1)` with fields `startscan` and `stopscan`. You need to delete all fields of `seg(1)`. Or fill with empty: either `seg(1).startscan = [];` or `[seg(IND).startscan] = deal([])`

Comment: I also tried

>>dummy=seg.startscan;
    seg.startscan = [ ];

but

??? Incorrect number of right hand side elements in dot name
assignment.  Missing [] around left hand side is a likely cause.


Is it this what you meant?
    dummy(inds)=[ ];
    seg.startscan = dummy;

Comment: @A_C: It seems you are trying something impossible. Could you put your input and your expected output in valid matlab syntax into your question? If you fail to do so, the expected output is probably not a valid data structure.

Comment: @Daniel good call on inputs/output... was a simpler problem than (i assume) we all thought

Comment: Can you just set it to an invalid value like NaN instead of erasing?

Comment: apparently not: ??? Scalar structure required for this assignment.

Answer (score 2):

To transform

> `seg.startscan = [1 2 3 4 5];`
>   `INDS = [1 3];`

into

> `seg.startscan = [2 4 5];`

you simply use

```
seg.startscan(INDS) = [];
```

Comment: That was actually my very first try. I updated the question. The error is ??? Scalar structure required for this assignment.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you want. Your question is very unclear. Did you paste my code as is?

Comment: Yes, and it works. But it doesn't work when I run the program. I really do not get why..

Comment: Did you forget deal()?